# Change selected text of a dropdown without changing the text in the option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

How to change the selected text of the dropdown without changing the text in the option? For ex: if dropdown has code and description both but on select i only wants to display the code and remove the description but description should be present in the dropdown.

Populating data in the dropdown:

```
$.each(jtc12_2_2_reasoncode1List, function(i, item) {
            $('#jtc12_2_reasonForFailure1').append($('<option>', {
                value : item.Code,
                text : item.Code + " " + item.Description
            }));
        });
```

Change the text of selected option:

```
 var jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1Code = $("#jtc12_2_reasonForFailure1 :selected").val();
        var jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1Desc = _.filter(e.data.jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1List, function(item) {
            return item.Code === jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1Code;
        });
        jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1Desc = jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1Desc[0].Description;
        $("#jtc12_2_reasonForFailure1 option[value = " + jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1Code + "]").text(jtc12_2_2_reasonCode1Code);
```

Comment: please include code that your tried

Comment: Please use a title that describes your question. There are literally tens of thousands of questions about jQuery and JavaScript, so just using that as a title is not very informative.

Comment: @NitinSharma, i think there is a miss in your requirement. If you set the text of selected option; its obvious that the description associated with that option will get vanished. "but description should be present in the dropdown" - where do you expect this to be preserved?

Comment: @NitinSharma. One way can be to use a textbox positioned above the dropdown - you can show any value you want in textbox based on dropdown's change event

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to add a new option at runtime and select that (the newly added) value instead of the selected value. Then the selected value can be removed on dropdown's click event.

Assuming the code and description are separated by a colon (:) refer the following code.

```
var onSelect = false;
$('select').click(function (e) {


    if ($(this).val() !== '' && !onSelect) {
        $(this).find('option:selected').remove();
    } else {

        onSelect = false;
    }
});

$('select').change(function (e) {

    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    var newVal = selectedVal.split(':')[0];
    $(this).append($('<option>', {
        value: newVal,
        text: newVal
    }));

    $(this).val(newVal);
    $(this).find('option:selected').hide();
    onSelect = true;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/8hu11wvs/)